# I want, when I press the delete button to delete the element that delet button represent.

Tags: javascript

I want to make the delete button that I've added to every li element to delete the exact element that he represents.
My code only removes the first child of the parent node.
I hope you guys understand what I want :)

```js
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = addElementsToList;

    //creating the function that adds elements to the unordered list

    function addElementsToList() {
        var liElements = document.createElement("LI");
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('text').value);
        var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
        var button = document.createElement("INPUT");



        button.setAttribute("type", "button");
        input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        liElements.className = "li";
        input.className = "checkbox";
        button.value = "Delete";

        button.className = "btn";
        var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
        for (var i = 0; i < btn.length - 1; i++) {
            btn[i].id = "btn";
        }
        console.log(btn);
        console.log(btn.length)

        liElements.appendChild(textNode);
        liElements.appendChild(input);
        liElements.appendChild(button);

        var paragraph1 = document.getElementById("elements").firstChild;
        document.getElementById("elements").insertBefore(liElements,paragraph1);

        //toggle done class
        var elementClasses = liElements.classList;
        function onCheckBoxChange() {
            liElements.addEventListener("change", function() {
                liElements.classList.toggle("done");
            });
        }

        button.onclick = removeElement;
        //function that removes the element
        function removeElement() {
            var list = document.getElementById('elements');
            list.removeChild(list.childNodes[0]);
        }

        onCheckBoxChange();

        return false;
    }

};
```

```css
body {
    background: #f9bc02;
}

#container {
    background: #fb9902;
    width: 60%;
    margin:20px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

#form {
    background: #fb9902;
    width: 50%;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

#text {
    width:75%;
    height:50px;
    border:0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

#submit {
    width:20%;
    height:50px;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#ul_elements {
    background: #fb9902;
    width: 50%;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}

.li{
    color:#fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    max-width: 65%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.checkbox {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    position: absolute;
    left:60%;
}
.done {
    color:green;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <lang>
        <title>ToDoList_2</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <h1>To do list</h1>
            </header>
            <form id="form">
                    <input type="text"  id="text"  value="Type here!" class="input">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="input">
            </form>
            <div id="ul_elements">
                <ul id="elements">
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: This is just something that I've tryed, ignore it :)
`button.className = "btn";
        var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
        for (var i = 0; i < btn.length - 1; i++) {
            btn[i].id = "btn";
        }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use event to get target element to delete exact element. Try below code.

```js
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("form").onsubmit = addElementsToList;

    //creating the function that adds elements to the unordered list

    function addElementsToList() {
        var liElements = document.createElement("LI");
        var textNode = document.createTextNode(document.getElementById('text').value);
        var input = document.createElement("INPUT");
        var button = document.createElement("INPUT");



        button.setAttribute("type", "button");
        input.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
        liElements.className = "li";
        input.className = "checkbox";
        button.value = "Delete";

        button.className = "btn";
        var btn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
        for (var i = 0; i < btn.length - 1; i++) {
            btn[i].id = "btn";
        }
        console.log(btn);
        console.log(btn.length)

        liElements.appendChild(textNode);
        liElements.appendChild(input);
        liElements.appendChild(button);

        var paragraph1 = document.getElementById("elements").firstChild;
        document.getElementById("elements").insertBefore(liElements,paragraph1);

        //toggle done class
        var elementClasses = liElements.classList;
        function onCheckBoxChange() {
            liElements.addEventListener("change", function() {
                liElements.classList.toggle("done");
            });
        }

        button.onclick = removeElement;
        //function that removes the element
        function removeElement(event) {
            var list = document.getElementById('elements');

            list.removeChild(event.target.parentElement);
        }

        onCheckBoxChange();

        return false;
    }

};
```

```css
body {
    background: #f9bc02;
}

#container {
    background: #fb9902;
    width: 60%;
    margin:20px auto;
    overflow: auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

#form {
    background: #fb9902;
    width: 50%;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

#text {
    width:75%;
    height:50px;
    border:0;
    border-radius: 15px;
    background-color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
}

#submit {
    width:20%;
    height:50px;
    border: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    cursor:pointer;
}

#ul_elements {
    background: #fb9902;
    width: 50%;
    margin:20px auto;
    padding: 20px;
}

header {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

li {
    text-align: left;
    display: block;
}

.li{
    color:#fff;
    text-align: left;
    font-size: 35px;
    font-weight: bolder;
    max-width: 65%;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
}

.checkbox {
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    position: absolute;
    left:60%;
}
.done {
    color:green;
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <lang>
        <title>ToDoList_2</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="js/script.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <head>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <header>
                <h1>To do list</h1>
            </header>
            <form id="form">
                    <input type="text"  id="text"  value="Type here!" class="input">
                    <input type="submit" value="Submit" id="submit" class="input">
            </form>
            <div id="ul_elements">
                <ul id="elements">
                    
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great ! Vote it up that will help me.